Avoiding MSBuild version with GitHub action
Currently in my github actions i am using
"  uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1"
instead of updating this to newest version i was wondering if it's good idea to use @main insted to avoid future updates for news versions.
"uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@main"
it seems working but i was not able to find that anyone uses this
